# WMI to change logging levels in WCF?

Tags: wcf, logging, wmi, trace, levels

I see a bunch of articles on MSDN on how WMI can do all kinds of things, and even a mention of how I can use AppDomainInfo to change the logging and tracing levels at runtime using WMI, but no code examples or implementations anywhere.

Has anyone done this? I'm using .net 4.0..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used WMI Tools CIM Studio to do this successfully. It's pretty slick to change logging levels at runtime without restarting IIS. You can download it from Microsoft.